# Altering dictionaries/keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have ran the code below in Python to generate a list of words and their count from a text file. How would I go about filtering out words from my "frequency_list" variable that only have a count of 1?

In addition, how would I export the print statement loop at the bottom to a CSV

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

```
import re
import string
frequency = {}
document_text = open('Words.txt', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{3,15}\b', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()



for words in frequency_list:
    print (words, frequency[words])
```

Comment: Iterate over key, value pairs using [one of these ```dict``` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict); test the value for your condition; store keys that meet the requirement in a container (like a list); use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to write to a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter out words, an alternative way would be:

```
frequency = dict(filter(lambda (k,v): v>1, frequency.items()))
```

To export the print statement loop at the bottom to a CSV, you could do that:

```
import csv    
frequency_list = ['word1','word2','word3']  # example

with open('output.csv','w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(frequency_list)
```

This will generate an 'output.csv' file with the words from your frequency_list in *one row*.

To get *a row for each word* try, the following:

```
with open('output.csv','w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerows([i.strip() for i in l.split(',')] for l in frequency_list)
```

> Update

To get a csv with the counters, keep your initial dictionary and do the following:

```
frequency = {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3} #example
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for key, value in frequency.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Using that last export example, how would I bring along the count value mentioned above to the CSV? So that each row (word) also has its respective count in a column next to it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part - you can use dict comprehension:

`frequency = {k:v for k,v in frequency.items() if v>1}`